# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, sub code=0x0). error while making queue

Tags: swift

I made Queue using list for practicing.

When I use peek([Int]) and remove([Int])

Xcode shows

> > fatal error: Index out of range

I made removeItem = [Int] for putting in deleted value,

when value goes in, it gets the error.

Since I am practicing, I would know why it is occurred.

Please explain it for me.

```
class QueNode
{
var queData : Int?
var link    : QueNode?
}

class QueList
{
var front : QueNode?
var rear : QueNode?


func isEmpty() -> Bool
{
    return (front == nil)
}

func insert(inputData : Int)  {

    var newNode = QueNode()
    newNode.link = nil
    newNode.queData = inputData



    if (isEmpty())
    {
        rear = newNode
        front = newNode
    }
    else
    {
        rear?.link = newNode
        rear       = newNode

    }

}

func remove(var item : [Int]) -> Bool
{

    if isEmpty()
    {
        print("empty que")
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        item[0] = front!.queData!
        front = front?.link
        if front == nil {

            rear = nil
        }
            return true
    }
}
func peek( var item : [Int]) -> Bool {
    if isEmpty() {
        print("empty que")

        return false
    }else
    {
        item[0] = (front!.queData)!
        return true
    }
   }
 }

var aQueue = QueList()
var insertItem = Int()

for i in 0..<3
 {
insertItem = (i + 1) * 10
aQueue.insert(insertItem)
print(insertItem)}




var removeItem = [Int]()

while aQueue.remove(removeItem)   /////I have an index error here.
{
     print(removeItem[0])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.

One is that you can't use a subscript to append an item to an empty array.
The second is that a `var` parameter only affects mutability within the method (and is being deprecated).

To get what I think you want, you need to change the method and the call.

```
func remove(inout item : [Int]) -> Bool
{
    if isEmpty()
    {
        print("empty que")
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        item.insert(front!.queData!, atIndex: 0)
        front = front?.link
        if front == nil {

            rear = nil
        }
        return true
    }
}

//...

while aQueue.remove(&removeItem)
{
    print(removeItem[0])
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain me what is inout and  & in front of the removeItem in simple way?I have searched those, those are quiet complicated to me.

Comment: It means that you're passing a variable **in** and, if you modify it, the new value is also passed **out** and therefore updates the caller's variable too.  The `&` is a throwback to how this was accomplished in C, which was to pass the address of the caller's variable rather than its value.